# How to connect a laptop that has an HDMI out to a monitor that has a Mini DisplayPort cable?

Tags: laptop, video, hdmi, displayport, mini-displayport

Concretely, a [Lenovo Y500](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tech-specs/laptop/ideapad/y-series/y500/) to a [Apple Cinema Display](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC007LL/A/apple-led-cinema-display-%2827%22-flat-panel%29).

**Note:** I would like to transfer a 2560x1440 resolution!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a converter/adapter from various sources.  [Startech](http://ca.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/HDMI-or-DVI-to-DisplayPort-Active-Converter~HDMI2DP) has an option.  They also have a configuration tool that lets you select their various converters and cables [Conxit](http://ca.startech.com/conxit)

Answer (score 1):

[HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) and [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) are two different ways to transfer video signals. Since these two are incompatible you will need something which understand both signals and which can act as a translator.

In other words, you need was is a *converter*. Not a passive adapter or a a plain cable with both HDMI and [mini]DP connectors on them, though some of the items sold as 'DP to HDMI cable' are actually one of these despite the sellers incorrect labeling.

Searching the web for `HDMI "to Displayport"` yields a lot of results. Sadly most of them seem to be for "DP to HDMI", rather then "HDMI to DP". I found at least one device which came close, though it was limited to 1920x1200. Note how bulky it looks compared to most 'cables'. There are active electronics in there.

Though the example image is from startech, there are at least two other companies making similar devices. (E.g. Apple and Sapphire).

Disclaimer: I do not work for any of those three. They are just the first ones I found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[GeForce GT 650M Specifications](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-650m/specifications)

Display Support:

Maximum Digital Resolution: 3840 x 2160

Maximum VGA Resolution      : Up to 2048x1536

If not correct work, use external video card.

[High speed mini DisplayPort-to-HDMI™ adapter](http://www.clicktronic.com/nc/en/products/hdmi/productview/mini_displayporthdmiTM_adapterkabel_casual/)

max. resolution:   4K (2160p) 
(It is 3840×2160 (8.3 megapixels in the 16:9 aspect ratio) and is one of the two resolutions of Ultra-high-definition television)

Transmission modes:   digital audio and video signals

other supported standards:   3D, HDCP, DRM, E-DDC, E-EDID, 4K (2160i/p), Full HD (1080i/p), HD ready (720i/p), SDTV (480i/p)

max. transfer rate (Gb/s)   10,2

Comment: My question is, how to connect the laptop with the monitor.

Comment: http://www.clicktronic.com/nc/en/products/hdmi/productview/mini_displayporthdmiTM_adapterkabel_casual/

Comment: The cable you linked to is a `mini DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter`. The OP searches for a device which works the other way around. HDMI **to** miniDP. Since this is not a mere cable but involves active conversion you can not just turn the cable around.